# How can I use Android to add some additional data to geotiff images?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, android

I would like to create an application which will use a geotiff image and add some additional data on it. All these with the Android Platform.
I've done some research and found GDAL but I don't know if there is something else which exists?

Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Mobile Atlas Creator to create tiles for your geotiff and create a zip file of the tiles - in combination with OSMDroid

*"The easisest way is to download MOBAC, then run it and mark out an area you want, store the tiles in Osmdroid.zip format. When that's done, drop the zip file into the osmdroid folder on your device."*
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747765/how-can-download-map-in-osmdroid/9749861#9749861

OSMDroid

http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/

Mobile Atlas Creator

http://mobac.sourceforge.net/

Your result is a zoom-able pan-able version of your GEOTIFF

Comment: Thank you Mapperz for your response !!

But with this method, I can only create tiles from OpenStreetMap Mapnik, OpenStreetMap Osmrender, OpenStreetMap Cyclemap, OpenStreetMap Public Transport and not with my Geotiff file, otherwise I don't understand how to transform geotiff file on an osmdroid format with MOBAC ...

Comment: I think you missed the point - you can chop your geotiff into the correct sizes and zip it up and replace the existing zip file (it just in the correct format to view)

Comment: ok, if I understand well what you say, I have to create with MOBAC, an osmdroid zip format of the area of my geotiff file, then drop it into the osmdroid folder on my device, then replace it with my geotiff file zipped ?

Comment: yes, it seems to work well.